# Azure availability set: IIS + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, iis

Can someone please explain me what I need to do in order to make my websites  available all the time using Microsoft azure.

At the moment I have just **one** dedicated server with IIS (running 7 websites) and SQL Server - all on one machine. Beside this I use Redis-lab as cloud service for hosting Redis cache.

I'm more or less happy how this works, but in case that something happens with server, or I need to restart it of course my website goes down which is not good of course.

So in order to make mitigate some of risks what exactly I need to do?

Am I correct in flowing thinking?

Option 1 - I need one more machine in an availability set with load balancer. This solution is not great as one server will still have an instance of SQL Server running = if that server goes down, websites on the second server will not work as the database is down

Option 2 - I need 3 more servers. 2 for IIS in a load balanced environment and 2 for SQL Server - which is super expensive solution.

Option 3 - 2 more servers. Where existing server and the new one will be for IIS (load balanced) + 3rd server with database. The database server will be write only. Both IIS severs will have an instance of ms SQL running in readonly mode => content from database server will be replicated to their databases. In this scenario if SQL Server goes down websites will still work as they will pull data from their own read only databases

Are there any other options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding other options have you considered the option of moving the databases to Azure SQL which would give you redundancy out of the box? Similarly if you can move the websites to Azure App Service you can get the same for the sites.

Comment: I've tested in the past speed of Azure SQL and was extremely unhappy. In order to reach the same speed as on the current server (IIS + SQL Server on the same machine) I needed to go for an option which costs more than a dedicated server. 

Regarding you second suggestion I've never thought about it. Will read a few articles

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely need the availability set for your deployment. Please, take a look at [Azure availability checklist](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-availability-checklist/) written by Microsoft.

I would propose you to migrate your web apps to the Azure Web Apps + set up the SQL Server deployment according to the [availability best practices](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-high-availability-dr/). Migrating them to the web apps as a service will eliminate some administrative tasks and the problem of placing all of the eggs in the same basket. You can place them to the one Web Apps Pricing Plan and change that plan when needed, for example, from more powerful resources to least powerful (or from the paid one to the free one for all of your sites).

If SQL Azure is not a solution for you, and (from my point of view) the data source is more critical than frontent/.../, it is highly recommended to deploy SQL Sever according to the tutorials provided above.

Comment: Thanks for the links! But converting web apps to Azure Web Apps is quite expensive. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but each application (if I select e.g. S1) is $74 per month. At the moment, I have 4 sites that would cost much more than having two dedicated servers.

Also, how would you solve a problem of uploading images via admin and showing them on the frontend? On the existing server I have one folder and both frotnend and admin are pointing to it via virtual directories.

Comment: That is the question of how much resources your websites are using. That should measured through the time to understand if your website needs S1 resources or not. You can create it in the Free mode. One shared folder, indeed, will add some coding and infrastructure efforts, so it can be a blocker for PaaS for you. So, your situation needs more thorough analysis and discussion that can not be covered in one question and discussion as it involves a lot of options and demands a lot of actions and measurements. :-) You can provide them to give more insight into your situation.